squid webproxy online but no responding
I would like to set up a Squid proxy, but I keep getting the following error message:
Source (webproxy) is online, but not responding to connection attempts. The remote computer is not responding to connection attempts on port 3128, possibly due to firewall settings or security policies, or because the remote computer is temporarily unavailable. There are no issues found with the firewall on your computer.

From the client PC, I can ping the computer where the Squid proxy is running, but nothing works with the proxy.
This is my squid.conf file:
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# ACL definitions for local networks that should have access
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8         # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12      # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16     # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7           # RFC 4193 local private network
acl localnet src fe80::/10          # RFC 4291 link-local (directly connected) machines

# ACL definitions for safe ports and methods
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80              # http
acl Safe_ports port 21              # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443             # https
acl Safe_ports port 70              # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210             # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535      # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280             # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488             # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591             # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777             # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended access rights:
#

# Allow cache management access only from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# Deny requests to unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Deny access to localhost from external clients
http_access deny to_localhost

#
# Access rules for your network
#

# Allow access for local networks
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid listens on IP address 192.168.0.0 and port 3128
http_port 192.168.0.0:3128

# Specify the location of log files
cache_log C:\squid\var\log\cache.log
access_log C:\squid\var\log\access.log

# Core dumps location
coredump_dir C:\squid\var\cache

# Refresh patterns for different protocols
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%      0
refresh_pattern .           0       20%     4320

# DNS servers that Squid should use
dns_nameservers 8.8.8.8 208.67.222.222

# Maximum number of file descriptors
max_filedescriptors 3200

# Debug options to control log level
debug_options ALL,1

How can I solve this?
